# performance/efficiency regarding multiple small Entity Framework queries in 1 method

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core

I'm a relatively new programming student, who's in the middle of writing some validation to check data integrity for an "adminSiteUser" entity in EF Core before updating said user with new info (I'm using a microsoft sql-server).

My code looks like this:

**AdminSiteUserServices.cs**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Edits an admin site user
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.NullReferenceException">thrown if user ID or department name doesn't match anything in DB</exception>
    /// <param name="editedAdminSiteUser"></param>
    public void EditAdminSiteUser(AdminSiteUserDTO editedAdminSiteUser)
    {
        //Gets user to be updated. If not found, throw new NullReferenceException
        AdminSiteUser adminSiteUser = _context.AdminSiteUsers.Include(asu => asu.adminSiteUserDepartments).FirstOrDefault(asu => asu.AdminSiteUserID == editedAdminSiteUser.UserID) 
            ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find admin site user in the database");

        List<AdminSiteUserDepartment> adminSiteUserDepartments = new List<AdminSiteUserDepartment>();


        //Gets the new departments the admin site user will be a member of. If not found, throw new NullReferenceException
        foreach (string item in editedAdminSiteUser.Departments)
        {
            Department department = _context.Departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentName == item)
                ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find department in the database");

            //Many-to-Many relation between admin site users and departments
            adminSiteUserDepartments.Add(new AdminSiteUserDepartment
            {
                AdminSiteUser = adminSiteUser,
                Department = department
            });
        }

        adminSiteUser.adminSiteUserDepartments = adminSiteUserDepartments;
        adminSiteUser.FirstName = editedAdminSiteUser.FirstName;
        adminSiteUser.LastName = editedAdminSiteUser.LastName;
        adminSiteUser.Username = editedAdminSiteUser.Username;


        _context.Update(adminSiteUser);
    }
```

Now, as far as I understand regarding EF Core, when I iterate through the foreach, EF should be making 1 query per iteration. What I'm wondering is how much influence something like this would have in performance in general against something like 1 query that checked through them all in 1 go.

I should add that this operation will only happen once in a while, since updating an admin site user won't happen so often, but I just got curious how much something like this could potentially influence performance, because I have another method (completely unrelated to this piece of code I'm currently showing) that only runs 1 query per method call, but will be called on average around 300-400 times a day, which I could more easily keep data integrity on if I add another query in the method, but I'm afraid of the impact on performance it could cause.

Comment: From my experiences, if you run EF on MSSQL, it could handle between 4k-10k small operations by minutes. If this run only 400/day you should not see a performance degradation. In another hand, why do you need to check for integrity? Does other programs could write in the database without you knowing?

Comment: if you are worried about small operations you could select whole departments list and do all the actions in memory. That will reduce requests to your database.

Comment: @JonathanLarouche it's because i made a foreign key relation between 2 tables through a non-primary key string column named username (normally don't do this) because this part of the program knows the users username, but not the userID (won't go into details regarding this situation), so i would have to make a query for the userID with the username as search parameter before making the relation (where i feared of the performance since i would double the amount of queries)

Comment: Hey @DavitMikuchadze, didn't think of that posibility, thanks

Comment: No problem, good luck.

Comment: @Docuventurer, Did you know that you could use Foreign Key on columns that are not Primary Keys? If the username have a UNIQUE key constraint, you can use it in foreign keys

Comment: @JonathanLarouche Well.. that is actually what i'm doing (if i get what you mean) with the following code: `modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogEntry>().HasOne(ue => ue.User).WithMany(u => u.UserLogEntries).HasForeignKey(p => p.Username).HasPrincipalKey(u => u.Username).IsRequired(true);` I guess i didn't express myself properly with the words data integrity. I only meant it in the form of checking if the admin site user and the departments still existed in the DB before actually trying to use their info during an update

Comment: Got it, you probably use Code First approach. I don't know how to handle multiple keys in an Entity to ensure the constraint gets configured correctly in the SQL database.

Comment: @JonathanLarouche But i'll still thank you for your first comment. it helped adjusting the scale i need to think when thinking about performance issues related to databases (or at least ms sql server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to avoid RBAR (Row by Agonizing Row) as much as possible.  The less round trips to the database, the better.

Taking a closer look at your foreach loop, you can make some significant improvements.

```
var departments = _context.Departments.Where(d => editAdminSiteUser
                     .Departments.Contains(d.DepartmentName)).ToList(); //query executes once here

//There is no query execution in the loop
foreach (string item in editedAdminSiteUser.Departments)
{
    departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentName == item)
            ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find department in the database");

        //Many-to-Many relation between admin site users and departments
        adminSiteUserDepartments.Add(new AdminSiteUserDepartment
        {
            AdminSiteUser = adminSiteUser,
            Department = department
        });
}
```

You have all the information to only get the departments you need, so no need to make multiple trips to the database.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you are not calling _context.SaveChanges() in this method.  Is it in the calling method?  Just so you know, adds and updates are not sent to the database until _context.SaveChanges() is called.  What's nice is that you can have multiple adds and updates, and only call _context.SaveChanges() once.  This will wrap it all in a transaction and make a single round trip to the database.

Comment: My apologies, I just noticed that @DavitMikuchadze suggested this in the comments.  This answer expands on his statement.

Comment: while my question primarily was concerned about performance impact of many small queries, Jonathan Larouche's comment answered my main concern, so i'll mark your answer as the accepted answer since it's currently the best example of improving the code i supplied. Thanks for the help